# Only one hostname (Like host.com) on a couchdb instalation access

Tags: dns, couchdb, nosql

I have a recent installation of CouchDB in my Debian VPS, all works fine, but can be accessed via IP, and via all of the domains in my server, and I want only one domain for this, for example, host.com:5984/_utils/index.html but not accessible in anotherhost.com:5984/_utils/index.html neither IP, How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch that add such feature for 2.0 will land [very soon](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-couch/pull/75).

As for now, you'll have to setup frontend proxy line nginx which will accept only requests with the Host header you allow. Certainly, in such case you'll need to serve CouchDB on localhost address to not let it be accessible freely from the world.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have Couchdb 1.6.1, so I will update to 2 when stable. 

But I have my CouchDB in my serve to serve info to App, so I can't have it in local.

Thanks!

Comment: You could solve this by proxying all requests to your CouchDB through your server. This way it is not accessible to the world, it is filtered through your webserver. I know one of the big draws of CouchDB is that you can access it through HTTP, but this should not be at the expense of security, and is mitigated by proxying, so beyond validation, requests go straight through to the database.